# Javascript class composition : access attribute of secondary class in attribute of main class

Tags: javascript, class, methods, attributes, composition

Let's take this exemple :

```
class A {
    attrA = 3;
}

class B {
    constructor() {
        this.a = new A;
    }
    attrB = this.a.attrA;
    methB() { console.log(this.a.attrA);}
}

const test = new B;

console.log(test.attrB);
test.methB();
```

I can access the class A attribute through method of class B, but I can't use it with attribute of class B, I have an "undefined" error.

The only way to do this is :

```
class A {
    attrA = 3;
}

class B {
    constructor() {
        this.a = new A;
        this.z = this.a.attrA
    }
    methB() { console.log(this.a.attrA);}
}

const test = new B;

console.log(test.z);
test.methB();
```

Why I need to put the attribute in the constructor and not the method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **think of class fields as being hoisted**, meaning this:

```js
class Example {
  constructor() {/*...*/}
  property = "value";
}
```

Is "actually" this:

```js
class Example {
  property = "value";
  constructor() {/*...*/}
}
```

Or (similar to) this:

```js
class Example {
  constructor() {
    this.property = "value";
    /*...*/
  }
}
```

Further, **identifiers are resolved upon access**. So by the time you execute `test.methB()`, `test.a` has been initialized, allowing the method to correctly resolve `this.a.attrA`. It works the same as this code:

```js
let variable = null;
const logVariable = () => console.log(variable); // You may think this logs null, but ...

variable = "value";
logVariable(); // ... it actually logs `variable`'s value at the time of calling.
```

As you have observed, mixing property initializations from within the constructor and using field initializers may be confusing. Therefore, a more intuitive way to write your code would be:

```js
class A {
  attrA = 3;
}

class B {
  a = new A;
  attrB = this.a.attrA;
  
  constructor() {}
  
  methB() {
    console.log(this.a.attrA);
  }
}

const test = new B;

console.log(test.attrB); // Works now!
test.methB();
```

Personal recommendations:

- Declare all instance and class fields.
- Prefer field initializers.
- Only reassign/initialize fields in the constructor for non-default values.

You may want to **read on for more details** for a better technical understanding.

---

## Class syntax

Classes are just uncallable constructor functions:

```js
class Example {}

console.log(typeof Example); // "function"
Example(); // Error: cannot be invoked without `new`
```

This is a quirk of the **ES6 class syntax**. Technically, class constructors are still "callable", but only internally (which happens when using `new`). Otherwise constructors would serve no purpose.

Another aspect of the class syntax is the ability to call `super()` in the constructor. This only comes into play when a class inherits, but that comes with yet its own quirks:

*You cannot use `this` before calling `super`:*

```js
class A {};
class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    this; // Error: must call super before accessing this
    super();
  }
}

new B();
```

Reason being, before calling `super` no object has been created, despite having used `new` and being *in the constructor*.

The actual object creation happens *at the base class*, which is in the most nested call to `super`. Only after calling `super` has an object been created, allowing the use of `this` in the respective constructor.

### Class fields

With the addition of **instance fields in ES13**, constructors became even more complicated: Initialization of those fields happens *immediately after* the object creation or the call to `super`, meaning before the statements that follow.

```js
class A /*no heritage*/ {
  property = "a";

  constructor() {
    // Initializing instance fields

    // ... (your code)
  }
}

class B extends A {
  property = "b";

  constructor() {
    super();
    // Initializing instance fields

    // ... (your code)
  }
}
```

Further, those property "assignments" are actually no assignments but definitions:

```js
class Setter {
  set property(value) {
    console.log("Value:", value);
  }
}
class A extends Setter {
  property = "from A";
}
class B extends Setter {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // Works effectively like class A:
    Object.defineProperty(this, "property", { value: "from B" });
  }
}
class C extends Setter {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.property = "from C";
  }
}

new A(); // No output, expected: "Value: from A"
new B(); // No output, expected: "Value: from B"
new C(); // Output: "Value: from C"
```

## Variables

Identifiers are only resolved upon access, allowing this unintuitive code:

```js
const logNumber = () => console.log(number); // References `number` before its declaration, but ...
const number = 0;

logNumber(); // ... it is resolved here, making it valid.
```

Also, identifiers are looked up from the nearest to the farthest lexical environment. This allows variable shadowing:

```js
const variable = "initial-value";

{
  const variable = "other-value"; // Does NOT reassign, but *shadows* outer `variable`.
  console.log(variable);
}

console.log(variable);
```